# Get IP address when implementing IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Does anyone know how to get a remote IP address when implementing IdentityServer4's IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator using c#?

***** Edit

Thanks to leastprivilege who put me on the right track i've now got the following:

My UserValidationService [IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator] class has:

```
public UserValidationService(ISecurity SecurityRepo, IHttpContextAccessor HttpContext)
{
        _securityRepo = SecurityRepo;
        _httpContext = HttpContext;
}
```

and my setup.cs class has:

```
var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer()
                                .AddSigningCredential(key)
                                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()                                 .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())                                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());


identityServer.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
identityServer.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();            
                identityServer.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>(x => new UserValidationService(bllFactory.GetInstance<ISecurity>()));
```

I'm getting an error of

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'HttpContext' of 'UserValidationService.UserValidationService(ISecurity, IHttpContextAccessor)

I understand the error message, but the examples I've seen online don't manually send in IHttpContextAccessor.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your implementation.

From there you get access to the HttContext - and then to the request.